# No funciona instalación de certificado de seguridad en web logic 12c

Tags: java, weblogic

Llevo varios días intentando hacer funcionar la instalación de un certificado ssl en weblogic 12c, el comando de instalación es el siguiente:

Keytool -import -alias certifcado.com -file "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\security\certificado.com.crt" -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit

El certificado se instala bien, y en la configuración del almacen de claves del servidor y la configuración ssl, la tengo como en el manual de instalación de mi organización, pero al probar, no funciona y me manda este mensaje desde la consola weblogic:

No se puede encontrar el archivo de almacén de claves de identidad nulo en el servidor AdminServer
Cargando certificados confiables desde el archivo del almacén de claves jks C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK18~1.0_2\jre\lib\security\cacerts

Cabe recalcar que el certificado se encuentra en esa ruta, y el almacen de claves del weblogic, también apunta ahí, pero no funciona y ya no sé que hacer.

Comment: ¡Ojo con la dirección que estás mostrando! Pareciera ser información sensible.